# Good Cross-browser tri-state checkbox?

Tags: javascript, user-controls, checkbox, cross-browser

Hey guys, I'm looking for a nice tri-state checkbox controller in JS ? 
Got anything to recommend me?

The states I'm looking for are

1. Checked
2. Unchecked
3. Indifferent (Was never checked/unchecked)

Comment: What do you need the third state for?

Comment: We need this logically because we want to integrate this control to a treegrid control I've written that has items inheritence, and these checkbox will display the inheritence. For example, If a parent item's checkbox wasn't checked then I want to display on the child the indifferent state, to show the user this checkbox has no default value yet, and is yet to be determined. I have a diffrent logic for radiobuttons control for these items.

Answer (score 1):

Use radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="tristate" value="checked" />Checked
<input type="radio" name="tristate" value="unchecked" />Unchecked
```

If none if the radios are turned on, then you have your third "indifferent" or null state.

Comment: My employer requires a checkbox control, it's a must for the UI

Comment: If it must be a checkbox, maybe you could incorporate the disabled functionality.  ex. If a parent item's checkbox wasn't checked then the checkbox could be disabled on the child to represent the indifferent state.  Of course, this doesn't work if you need to be able to change the child's state before the parent is set.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into EXTJS.

They have a big community that often builds things like this and I'm sure if you googled for one it might come up. Actually here you go you may be able to make a few changes to this and get it to work how you want:

http://extjs.net/forum/showthread.php?t=28096

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I developed this solution while working on a project. It uses the indeterminate state of checkboxes (an attribute that cannot be accessed / set from markup).  In my example, I have just one level of nesting but it can be nested indefinitely to allow for groups and sub-groups to be un, all, or partially selected.

The basic structure revolves around manipulating the indeterminate attribute like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="HasFavoriteColor" name="FavoriteColor" id="myCheckBox" />
<input type="hidden" id="FavoriteColorState" name="FavoriteColorState" /><!-- potential values: 0, 1, -1 -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    //using JQuery
    $("#myCheckBox").prop("indeterminate", true);

    //using pure javascript
    document.getElementById("myCheckBox").setAttribute("indeterminate", true);
</script>
```

I used it for a select-all here in my example, but it could be used on just an individual checkbox.  It's important to know that this DOES NOT communicate state in a post-back to the server.  A checkbox being posted is still true / false so indeterminate only affects UI.  If you need to post values back, you will have to tie the indeterminate state to some hidden field to persist the value.

For more on the indeterminate state, see the following resources:

- http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html

Here is a working example (external fiddle):
http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/65wZt/

Working Example (Stack Snippet):

```js
var root = this;
root.selectedCount = 0;
root.totalCount = 0;
root.percentageSelected = 0.0;
root.holdTimer = 0;
jQuery.fn.customSelect = {
    State: 0,
    NextState: function () {
        this.State += 1;
        if (this.State > 2) {
            this.State = 0;
        } // end if
    } // end object
};

function checkAllToggle(parent, toggle) {
    if (parent != null && parent != undefined) {
        parent.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", toggle);
        for (var i = 0; i < parent.find("input[type='checkbox']").length; i++) {
            $(document).trigger("item-selected", {
                IsSelected: $(parent.find("input[type='checkbox']")[i]).prop("checked")
            });
        } // end for loop
    } // end if
} // end function checkAll
var fadeTimer = setInterval(function () {
    if (root.holdTimer > 0) {
        root.holdTimer -= 1;
    } else {
        root.holdTimer = -2;
    } // end if/else
    if (root.holdTimer == -2) {
        $(".options-status").fadeOut("easeOutBack");
        root.holdTimer = -1;
    } // end if/else
}, 50);
$(function () {
    root.totalCount = $(document).find(".options-list input[type='checkbox']").length;
    $(document).bind("select-state-change", function (e, data) {
        switch (data.State) {
            case 0:
                data.Target.prop("checked", false);
                data.Target.prop("indeterminate", false);
                checkAllToggle($(".options-list"), false);
                break;
            case 1:
                data.Target.prop("indeterminate", true);
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            case 2:
                data.Target.prop("checked", true);
                data.Target.prop("indeterminate", false);
                checkAllToggle($(".options-list"), true);
                break;
        }

    });
    $(document).bind("item-selected", function (e, data) {
        root.holdTimer = 50;
        if (data != null && data != undefined) {
            if (data.IsSelected) {
                root.selectedCount += 1;
            } else {
                root.selectedCount -= 1;
            } // end if/else
            if (root.selectedCount > root.totalCount) {
                root.selectedCount = root.totalCount;
            } // end if
            if (root.selectedCount < 0) {
                root.selectedCount = 0;
            } // end if
            root.percentageSelected = (100 * (root.selectedCount / root.totalCount));
            root.percentageSelected < 50 && root.percentageSelected >= 0 ? $(".options-status").removeClass("finally-there").removeClass("almost-there").addClass("not-there", 200) : false;
            root.percentageSelected < 100 && root.percentageSelected >= 50 ? $(".options-status").removeClass("not-there").removeClass("finally-there").addClass("almost-there", 200) : false;
            root.percentageSelected == 100 ? $(".options-status").removeClass("not-there").removeClass("almost-there").addClass("finally-there", 200) : false;
            $(".options-status .output").text(root.percentageSelected + "%");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".options-status").fadeIn("easeInBack");
            }, 100);
        } // end if
    });
    $("#select-all").click(function (e) {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        if (checkbox.prop("checked") == true) {
            checkbox.customSelect.State = 2;
        } else {
            checkbox.customSelect.State = 0;
        } // end if/else
        $(document).trigger("select-state-change", {
            State: checkbox.customSelect.State,
            Target: $("#select-all")
        });
    });
    $("input[name='options']").each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                $(document).trigger("item-selected", {
                    IsSelected: true
                });
                if ($(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='checkbox']").length) {
                    $(document).trigger("select-state-change", {
                        State: 2,
                        Target: $("#select-all")
                    });
                } else {
                    $(document).trigger("select-state-change", {
                        State: 1,
                        Target: $("#select-all")
                    });
                } // end if/else
            } else {
                $(document).trigger("item-selected", {
                    IsSelected: false
                });
                if ($(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length <= 0) {
                    $(document).trigger("select-state-change", {
                        State: 0,
                        Target: $("#select-all")
                    });
                } else {
                    $(document).trigger("select-state-change", {
                        State: 1,
                        Target: $("#select-all")
                    });
                } // end if/else
            } // end if/else
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: small;
    color: #232323;
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
H1 {
    margin-top: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
LEGEND {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.content-wrapper {
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 3px auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 250px;
}
.wrapper {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
}
.container {
    border-right: solid 1px #788967;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #677867;
    border-top: solid 1px #89ab89;
    border-left: solid 1px #89ab89;
}
.rounded {
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.contents {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(180, 180, 180, .2));
}
.header {
    padding: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 230, .8);
    font-size: 123%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(220, 220, 255, .8), rgba(200, 200, 230, .8));
}
#options-chooser {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: block;
}
#options-chooser .options-list > LABEL {
    display: table-row;
    height: 26px;
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
.blue {
    color: blue;
}
.green {
    color: green;
}
.black {
    color: black;
}
.options-status {
    float: right;
    right: 3%;
    clear: both;
    display: none;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.output {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.not-there {
    border-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, .3);
    background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, .1);
}
.almost-there {
    border-color: rgba(220, 220, 50, .6);
    background-color: rgba(220, 220, 50, .3);
}
.finally-there {
    border-color: rgba(50, 190, 50, .3);
    background-color: rgba(50, 190, 50, .1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper container rounded">
        <div class="contents">
             <h1 class="header rounded">Partial Select All Example</h1>

            <p>This example demonstrates how to implement a tri-state checkbox with options.</p>
            <form name="options-chooser" id="options-chooser" method="post">
                <fieldset class="rounded options">
                    <legend class="rounded header">Options
                        <input type="checkbox" value="options-all" name="selectAll" id="select-all" title="Select All" />
                    </legend> <span class="options-status rounded container wrapper">Items Selected: <span class="output"></span></span>
                    <div class="options-list">
                        <label class="blue">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="1" />Blue</label>
                        <label class="green">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="2" />Green</label>
                        <label class="red">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="3" />Red</label>
                        <label class="black">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="4" />Black</label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than two states, then use 3 radio buttons.

Don't assume if the user didn't select anything to mean the third state.  What if the user missed the question all together, or hit submit by mistake?

If you want 3 states, then have 3 states!

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML5 indeterminate input elements](http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/).

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using a native checkbox and the indeterminate property and storing a custom attribute in the checkbox to capture the current state to achieve an effective triple state checkbox.

This solution has tested out well on latest Chrome and Firefox and chromium (nw.js) on Linux and IE 11, Firefox and Chrome on Windohs.

I have posted this solution to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaScriptDude/22adg13g/4/).

Here is the utility singleton I used:

```
tscb$ = {
     STATE_UNCHECKED: 0
    ,STATE_CHECKED: 1
    ,STATE_INDETER: 2
    ,setState:  function(o,iState){
        var t=this;
        if(iState==t.STATE_UNCHECKED){
            o.indeterminate=false; o.checked=false;
        } else if(iState==t.STATE_CHECKED){
            o.indeterminate=false; o.checked=true;
        } else if(iState==t.STATE_INDETER){
            o.checked=false; o.indeterminate=true;
        } else {
            throw new Error("Invalid state passed: `"+iState+"`")
        }
        o.setAttribute("tscbState", iState);
    }
    // Event to call when the cb is clicked to toggle setting.
    ,toggleOnClick:  function(o){
        var t=this, iNextState=t.getNextState(o)
        if(iNextState==t.STATE_UNCHECKED){
            o.checked=false;
        } else if(iNextState==t.STATE_CHECKED){
            o.checked=true;
        } else if(iNextState==t.STATE_INDETER){
            o.indeterminate=true;
        }
        o.setAttribute("tscbState", iNextState);
    }
    // For retrieval of next state 
    ,getNextState: function(o){
        var t=this, iState=t.getState(o)
        if(iState==t.STATE_UNCHECKED){
            return t.STATE_INDETER;
        } else if(iState==t.STATE_CHECKED){
            return t.STATE_UNCHECKED;
        } else if(iState==t.STATE_INDETER){
            return t.STATE_CHECKED;
        }
    }
    ,getState: function(o){
        return parseInt(o.getAttribute("tscbState"))
    }

}
```

Usage:

- tscb$.setState() is used to initialize or override a setting for a checkbox
- tscb$.toggleOnClick() is used when the element is clicked to toggle to the next state
- tscb$.getState() is to retrieve the current state
- tscb$.getNextState() is to retrieve the next state

Its amazing how effective a triple state checkbox can be at keeping a UI compact while allowing for unique filtering functionality. Its very effective for dynamic search result filtering where a filter can be True / False / Off with just one control